# How to code own consensus in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, consensus

I want to use Hyperledger Fabric. But I need a special consensus algorithm. I have the concept ready but no idea how to get it implemented in Fabric.

The documentation says:

> A consensus plugin needs to implement the Consenter and Chain
>   interfaces defined in the consensus package. There are two plugins
>   built against these interfaces already: solo and kafka. You can study
>   them to take cues for your own implementation. The ordering service
>   code can be found under the orderer package.

First question: Is it possible to code my own consensus method and run it in Hyperledger Fabric? Second: If yes, how should I start?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've just about answered your own question. The consensus algorithms in Hyperledger Fabric are implemented by the Ordering service. So, to implement a new algorithm, you would need to code a new consensus package, add this to the Ordering service, and a build a new fork of the fabric runtime.

Use one of the existing implementations as a starting point (solo or kafka), and have at it! :)